# C++ on Xcode 7.01 on El Capitan Error -> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, osx-elcapitan

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "makeHero(std::string, int)", referenced from:
   makeCard() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the error I am getting when I'm trying to compile my code on Xcode. I've looked around and I have changed Architecture settings to Universal, and have made c++ std library, libstdc++, which were answers I found on here. Still nothing :/

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string>

using namespace std;
```

Is the beginning of my main.cpp file whats causing it? I changed stdlib.h  and stdio.h to without the .h and I get stdlib file not found.

Comment: You need to work out which library provides the functions called `makeHero()` and `makeCard()` and then make sure that you link those libraries. So go in the `Project Editor`, and select the `Target` you want to add libraries for, then click `Build Phases` and `Link Binary with Libraries` and add the library providing `makeHero()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

This error message is rather misleading, what it's really telling you is that the compiler has seen a function declaration (symbol) for *makeHero(std::string, int)*, but can't find its implementation.

The error is simple to reproduce by declaring a function in a header file, without implementing the function's body in either the header or cpp.

To fix the problem, ensure the body for the function is implemented in the project.